# vimプラグイン NERDTree起動時にエラー

Tags: vim

[こちら](https://qiita.com/zwirky/items/0209579a635b4f9c95ee)と[こちら](https://qiita.com/yo-shi/items/c3b2e8b1c2d12e4fd2cc)を参考にしてvimプラグインNERDTreeを導入したのですが、コマンドでプラグインを起動させたところエラーが出てしまいます。
エラー表示後にenterを押すとプラグイン自体はちゃんと機能しているようでディレクトリの表示はされていました。

## 環境

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Vim 8.0.1283

## .vimrcに追記した内容

```
"NERDTree
set nocompatible
filetype off

if has('vim_starting')
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim
call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))
endif

"insert here your Neobundle plugins"
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

call neobundle#end()
    
filetype plugin indent on

"NERDTree toggle key
nnoremap <silent><C-e> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

## エラー内容

```
Error detected while processing /Users/xxxx/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/
syntax/nerdtree.vim:
line   44:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter
E15: Invalid expression: 'syn match NERDTreeNodeDelimiters #' . g:NER
DTreeNodeDelimiter . '# containedin=ALL'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

## /Users/xxxx/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/syntax/nerdtree.vim:line44あたりの記述

```
 39 "highlighing to conceal the delimiter around the file/dir name
 40 if has("conceal")
 41     exec 'syn match NERDTreeNodeDelimiters #' . g:NERDTreeNodeDel    imiter . '# conceal containedin=ALL'
 42     setlocal conceallevel=3 concealcursor=nvic
 43 else
 44     exec 'syn match NERDTreeNodeDelimiters #' . g:NERDTreeNodeDel    imiter . '# containedin=ALL'
 45     hi! link NERDTreeNodeDelimiters Ignore
 46 endif
 47
 48 syn match NERDTreeCWD #^[</].*$#
```

シンタックスが効いていないだけのような気がしますがエラーの内容がよくわかりませんでした。
自分なりにいろいろ試してみたのですがどうしても解決できません。
よろしければご助言よろしくお願いいたします。

## .vimrcを修正しました

```
"NERDTree
set nocompatible
filetype off

if has('vim_starting')
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim
endif

"insert here your Neobundle plugins"

  call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))

NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

  call neobundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on

syntax enable

"NERDTree toggle key
nnoremap <silent><C-e> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: Vimはわからないので申し訳ないですが、`.vimrc`の`endif`は、`call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))`
の前か`call neobundle#end()`の次の行でないといけないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ```neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))```の前と```call neobundle#end()```の後ろに変更して試してみましたがダメでした...
エラー内容も変化なしでした。
基本的な記述自体が間違っているのでしょうか...

Comment: お役に立てず申し訳ありませんでしたが、beginとendがif文の中と外にあるのは気持ち悪いので、今のまま原因を追跡して行かれた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: `filetype plugin indent on`のすぐ下の行に`syntax enable`を書いたら変化がありますか？（他の行に`syntax enable`、`syntax on`を書いていればそれはコメントアウトしてください）

Comment: ご指摘がありましたので.vimrcを修正し、質問欄に追加しましたがこのような記述で合っていますでしょうか？
```syntax enable```を追加してみましたがエラーに変化はありませんでした。

Comment: 参考: ["Error with the latest version · Issue #911 · scrooloose/nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/911)

Answer (score 2):

その後色々と修正が入ったようなので、最新版を試してみるとよさそうです。

参考: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/912

Comment: ありがとうございます！色々試してみます！